# Internal Server error while getting response from webapi using httpclient postasync in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, httpclient

```cs
_clientRequest = new CustomHttpClient(parameters.AppInstanceID, Cockpit4DIAConnection);
            
HttpContent requestParameter = new ObjectContent<ViewParameters>(parameters, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
HttpResponseMessage response = await _clientRequest.PostAsync(_Url + _PartialQueryResultAsString, requestParameter);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryWrapper>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

This partialqueryresult method have the data while transporting the data from api to this controller response came as internal server error 500 in .net core 3.1

I am migrating the application. It is working fine in the asp.net framework.

I have several methods with postasync. They are working fine.

Is there any issue with the response type?

Comment: An internal server error should result in an error appearing in the logs... have you checked your logs?

Comment: I havent used logging yet..any generic logs you are referring?

Comment: The web server logs. I would stop any other work until you know how to find the logs - otherwise it's like trying to work with your eyes closed.

Answer (score 0):

An internal server error is, well, internal to the server. It is not an error in the client.

However, it is possible that the server is badly handling a situation where you supplied it with incorrect information, therefore returning a 500 instead of a more informative explanation on what precisely you did wrong.

For example, suppose I send an ID to the server to fetch a resource that does not exist in the server's database. That should yield a 4xx status response (as this is a client mistake, not a server error), but if the server doesn't properly check for `null`, it will encounter a `NullReferenceException` which, when not handled, bubbles up to the endpoint and gets translated into a 500 internal server error.

It's not impossible that the final resolution will have to come from your client changing what it sends to the server, but this can only be confirmed after you debug the server (or simply read its logs) to find out what the cause of the internal server error is.